# How to provide an option to a C library via a macro

Tags: c, linker, c-preprocessor

I have the following source named `lcd.c`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lcd.h"

void print_mode(void)
{
  printf("%d\n",LCD_MODE);
}
```

The header `lcd.h` contains the definition for `LCD_MODE` as follows.

```
#ifndef LCD_H
#define LCD_H

#include "util.h"

#ifndef LCD_MODE
#define LCD_MODE LCD_MODE_8BIT
#endif

void print_mode(void);

#endif /* LCD_H */
```

The file `util.h` contains

```
#ifndef UTIL_H
#define UTIL_H

#define LCD_MODE_8BIT 1
#define LCD_MODE_4BIT 0

#endif /* UTIL_H */
```

`lcd.c` will be compiled separately as part of some library. I want to use it with an application `main.c` as follows.

```
#include "util.h"
#define LCD_MODE LCD_MODE_4BIT
#include "lcd.h"

int main(void)
{
  print_mode();
  return 0;
}
```

The desired outcome is to print `0` as per the definition of `LCD_MODE_4BIT` in `main.c`. However, `1` is printed because the header file sees that `LCD_MODE` is not defined during the preprocessing for `lcd.c`. How should I go about passing the `LCD_MODE` option to `print_mode()` through the main application?

Comment: can't you compile your code with `-DLCD_MODE=LCD_MODE_4BIT` option ? if not, then you're stuck.

Comment: If you need this to be configurable without recompiling the library, then don't use a macro.

Comment: You can pass the option as a parameter: `void print_mode(int lcd_mode);`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Ideally I'd like to not have to recompile `lcd.c` for every use case (i.e I want to have it as part of some larger static library). So I can't use the command-line definition. I guess there isn't another way...

Comment: the pre-processing hardcodes the value in `lcd.o` so yes, you're stuck unless you create a `set_mode` method

Comment: `#define` constants only exists at compile time. If you want them to be changeable without recompilation they should be parameters or global variables instead.

Comment: @DYZ Yeah I was considering that, but there will be many functions within `lcd.c` that will depend on `LCD_MODE`, which will result in having to pass in the argument for each of them. Maybe I can't avoid that after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you cannot recompile `lcd.c` you cannot use a macro in another source file, because `lcd.o` already has the value hardcoded.

You could create a static variable (which defaults to `LCD_MODE`) that you can change using a setter:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lcd.h"

static int the_mode = LCD_MODE;

void print_mode(void)
{
  printf("%d\n",the_mode);
}

void set_mode(int new_mode)
{
   the_mode = new_mode;
}
```

`lcd.h` should contain the prototype for the new configuration function BTW:

```
void set_mode(int new_mode);
```

then in your main, you can:

```
set_mode(LCD_MODE);
```

(or drop that `LCD_MODE` macro everywhere because it solves nothing and adds to the confusion)

Comment: beat me to it :(

Comment: I beat you to "you cannot do that" kind of answer, TBH :)